# Indent for item lost when using multicol

Tags: lists, indentation, multicol

I am struggling with some of the simple things and this has me stumped.

Below there is a part of my code and the output.
As you can see I am making a multiple-choice question template.
Question 2 is fine, but when I  try to make the `\item` answers go across the page the indent does not line up with the one above.
How can I fix this?

```
 \item {Question 2 words}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[(A)] Option A
        \item[(B)] Option B
        \item[(C)] Option C
        \item[(D)] Option D
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \item {Question 3 words}
     \begin{multicols}{2}
        \item [(A)] Option A    
        \item [(B)] Option B
        \item [(C)] Option C
        \item [(D)] Option D
    \end{multicols}
```

[image]

Comment: multicols takes over the entire page layout it can't adust to teh current item indent You could place a `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}` in the item, and then use multicols within that.  Note `\item` does not take an argumnet so `\item Question 3 words`  not `\item {Question 3 words}`

Comment: also please supply a complete test file that produces the image, you appear to be missing a nested `enumerate` for the inner lists.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on thhe minipage and {}. allowed me to solve it by doing this                                                     \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}   
    \item Question 3 words
     \begin{multicols}{2}
       {\setlength\itemindent{22pt}\item[(A)] Option A  
        \item [(B)] Option B}
        \item [(C)] Option C
        \item [(D)] Option D
   \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}

Comment: that is still wrong though, you are missing a `\begin{enumerate}` for the inner list (it just accidentally "works" as the `\item` are items of the outer list with over-written numbers.

Comment: Welcome. // Why don't you pick one of the exam-related packages? Some of them also provide evaluations. // E.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiple-choice seems to be close to what you're trying. // See https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam for all inthis category.